# How to find exact match of multiple values in a column?

Tags: sql

I need a query that returns all picklists that only have the specified UPCs (e.g. 038447302 and 00934831). The query I am currently have is using WHERE IN and so it returns all picklists that have the specified UPCs as well as any other UPC in the picklist.

```
SELECT 
  a.order_id, 
  a.id AS picklist_id, 
  SUM(p.quantity), 
  p.upc, 
  pick_zone, 
  a.STATUS 
FROM 
  picklists a 
  INNER JOIN picklist_items p ON p.picklist_id = a.id 
  INNER JOIN warehouse_orders f ON a.order_id = f.id 
WHERE 
  a.STATUS IN ('dropped') 
  AND f.status != 'cancelled' 
  and p.upc IN('038447302', '00934831') 
GROUP BY 
  a.STATUS, 
  a.picklist_group_id, 
  a.id, 
  a.order_id, 
  pick_zone
```

Comment: for your specific example you could add `having count(distinct p.upc = 2)`

Comment: I'm uncertain why, but when I add that it still returns picklists that contain the specified UPCs _and_ other UPCs.

Comment: Without any sample data to review and table schema with which to test, I too am uncertain.

Comment: Edit question to add tag for RDBMS used as well as sample data as text tables.